# How to show default partner_id in wizard which is selected in sale order form but not saved yet?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, default-value

I selected the customer name in the sales order form. And above the sale order line, I added a button, for this button wizard is opened and getting information from the customer. I want that in wizard customer name(partner_id) should be auto-filled when the user opens it. So, how can I do that?

**Wizard file code is:**

```
class RentalPackWizard(models.TransientModel):

    _name = "rental.pack.wizard"

    _description = "Rental Pack Wizard"

"""@api.model

    def _get_default_partner(self):

        partner = self.env['res.partner'].search([()], limit=1)

        return partner"""

    ser6_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer')# , default=_get_default_partner)
```

Also Attached image for problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` use `context` to pass values.

Example:

```
  context="{'default_partner_id':partner_id}"
```

Comment: Hii @KbiR.. following error showing "Error: NameError: name 'partner_id' is not defined"

Comment: @pawan, above code is just sample. You need to pass the field you defined `many2one` for `res.partner` in parent view.

Comment: Actually i want too partner_id field.

Comment: I think, in sale order there is partner_id field for customer. how do you open wizard? Post that code also.